# How to pass formcollection using ajax call to an action?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to replace a form submit with ajax call. the action needs formcollection and I don't want to create a new Model. So I need to pass the whole form (just like form submit) but through ajax call. 
I tried to serialize and using Json but the formcollection is empty. 
this is my action signature:

```
public ActionResult CompleteRegisteration(FormCollection formCollection)
```

and here is my submit button click:

```
var form = $("#onlineform").serialize();              
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Register/CompleteRegisteration",                
                datatype: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(form),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.result == "Error") {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
```

now how can I pass data into formcollection?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since `FormCollection` is a number of key-value pairs, JSON is inappropriate data format for its representation. You should use just serialized form string:

```
var form = $("#onlineform").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Register/CompleteRegisteration",
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.result == "Error") {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    }
});
```

Key changes:

1. **type** of the request set to POST (not necessary here, but seems more natural)
2. Serialized form instead of JSON string as request **data**
3. **contentType** removed - we are not sending JSON anymore

Comment: There should be "," after type: 'POST' line

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$(<your form>).on('submit',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Register/CompleteRegisteration" + $(this).serialize(), 
        // place the serialized inputs in the ajax call                
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result == "Error") {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Attaching the ajax call to submit was the key!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone want to pass additional data to the FormCollection then you can try below.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function SubmitInfo() 
{
    var id = $("#txtid").val();    
    var formData = $('#yourformname').serializeObject();
    $.extend(formData, { 'User': id }); //Send Additional data

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Controlle/GetUser',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: decodeURIComponent($.param(formData)),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#resultarea').html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
<script/>
```

Action Method

```
public ActionResult GetUser(FormCollection frm)
  {
   int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(frm["user"]);
   // your code
   return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

[Refer link](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2014/06/25/combining-jquery-form-serialize-and-json.stringify-when-doing-ajax-post.aspx) for more details.