# MVC 4 submit 2 forms with one button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a MVC 4 web application and need to submit two forms (maybe three forms) with one button. Is there a way to work around? or I have to merge the forms into one big form?

I searched around, found lots of the threads about "ONE FORM MULTI BUTTONS", but they are not what I am looking for.

Any suggestion, links, ideas are welcomed!

Comment: When you say three forms are you trying to send to multiple sources? For example, you own processor, MailChimp and PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

You can always submit more forms using Javascript.  Intercept the submit event, and use the boilerplate JQuery for Ajax-submitting a form:

```
$("#theFirstForm, #theSecondForm").on("submit", function(e) {

    // prevent the default form-post
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post($("#theFirstForm").prop('action'), $("#theFirstForm").serialize(), function() {
        // first form post complete 
    });

    $.post($("#theSecondForm").prop('action'), $("#theSecondForm").serialize(), function() {
        // second form post complete 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about no form and just sending a async post from javascript using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Check this if interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797053/how-to-pass-formcollection-using-ajax-call-to-an-action

Comment: Thanks this link looks interesting.