# Form not posting resource not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to post a a form to an MVC controller which takes a form collection using AJAX.  I have been following this [How to pass formcollection using ajax call to an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797053/how-to-pass-formcollection-using-ajax-call-to-an-action).  However when I make the post request to the controller it somehow reverses the order of the path e.g.  In my AJAX code my URL is `'/Settings/EditDatasource'` but when I make the post request it becomes `http://localhost:53658/EditDatasource/Settings`

Here is my AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#postEditDatasource').click(function (event) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(deletedDatapoints));
        //serialise and assign json data to hidden field
        $('#dsDeletedDP').val(JSON.stringify(deletedDatapoints));

        //anti forgery token
        //get the form
        var form = $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm');
        //from the form get the antiforgerytoken
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

        var URL = 'Web/Settings/EditDatasource';

        //we make an ajax call to the controller on click
        //because the controller has a AntiForgeryToken attribute
        //we need to get the token from the form and pass it with the ajax call.
        $.ajax({
            url: URL + form.serialize(),
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                if (data.result == "Error") {
                    ShowDatasourcePostAlert('failPost', 3000);
                } else {
                    ShowDatasourcePostAlert('successPost', 3000);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An error has occurred please contact admin");
            }
        })
    });
})
```

and here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditDatasource(FormCollection collection)
    {

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: Quick thoughts - `form.serialize()` should go in `Request Body`, but I see you are passing in URL. Also show us your controller action code.

Comment: @ramiramilu my controller isnt doing anything apart from returning an empty result as I dont want it to do anything after.  I shall post my code anyway along with the attribute tags

Comment: Have you tried removing `form.serialize()` in URL and passing it in `data` -  `data: form.serialize()`.

Comment: I have done it like this dsCollection: form.serialize() within the data block

Comment: no this is not working either

Comment: `data : { __RequestVerificationToken: token, collection: form.serialize()}`, try like this, and let me know the result.

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes the solution as below. Create a simple `POST Action`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyIndex(FormCollection collection)
{
    var fname = collection["FirstName"];
    var lname = collection["LastName"];
    return Json(true);
}
```

Let your HTML be -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBox("FirstName","Rami")
    <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" />
}

<input type="button" value="Click" id="btnSub" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSub').click(function () {        
        var form = $('#MyForm');
        console.log(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/MyIndex/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

And the output would be -

[image]

**NOTE:**
If you don't use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, then `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` will throw you the error. So there is no need for you to pass `AntiForgeryToken` explicitly in JQuery AJAX Post.

Comment: what if I have hidden fields?  what do I do then?

Comment: All hidden fields will be serialized and will be posted to server, no need of any extra work. In fact, Forgery Token is also an hidden field.

Comment: I will give this a go and let you know the results