# How to open a popup and post data to controller simultaneously using ajax call in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, popup, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to implement search functionality in my Form View. The search window opens in a popup (in a partialView) and asks for search queries([figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0cEg.png)). Now the user enters all the search fields and POST request is made and eventually popup window displays a table of search result.

**Form View** *(which has the button to open popup window)*

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Search current form", "SearchAction", new { @id = "SearchBtn" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openPopup" }, new { @class ="btn btn-primary"})<br />
<div id="result" style="display:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#result").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Search Window',
            resizable:0,
            width: 1000,
            height: 700,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    function openPopup() {
        $("#result").dialog("open");
    }
</script>
```

**SearchForm View** *(implemented as partial view)*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAction", "ViewModel", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "searchform" }))
{
    //some form elements

    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
}


<div class="alert-danger">@ViewBag.emptyResult</div>

@if (Model != null)
{
    //display the search results 
}
```

Now to retain the popup I have to bind **Go** button to a ajax action in the same way as Form View. Also by reading this [How to pass formcollection using ajax call to an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797053/how-to-pass-formcollection-using-ajax-call-to-an-action) I came to know that Ajax actions posts JSON data into the controller as opposed to key value pair which is easily accessible by FormCollection. So my question is how do I implement submit button(Ajax.Actionlink) in my search form so that it posts data into controller using FormCollection and retains the popup window as well.

Comment: If I am not getting wrong you want a pop up with search field and when you hit GO it's will show search result to your form, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to achieve. Although I've solved this and will update the answer soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to define a placeholder for the result table in my search popup.

```
<div id="showData" class="text-center table table-bordered bg-light"></div>
```

Now get your search results using Ajax call

```
function GetSearchResult() {
        var searchParams = [];
        //get search queries from textbox ids

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                s: searchParams
            },
            url: "/{controller name} /{action}",
            success: function (result) {
                var col = [];
                if (isJson(result)) {
                    var sR = JSON.parse(result);
                    //create a html table using javascript and fill it which the result you got
                var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
                divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                divContainer.appendChild(table);  //table is what you created dynamically using javascript
                }
                else {
                    alert("No results found, Please try again");    
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Add this action in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string value, string Id)
{
     var updatedList = GetSearchResults(); //get search result from your repository
     return Json(updatedList);
}
```

And as far as creating a html table thorugh javascript is concerned [this](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/dynamically-add-remove-rows-to-html-table-using-javascript-and-save-data.htm) helped me a lot!